# Android UPI pin wrong entered in PHONEPE returns Status as "Success" instead of "Failure"

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[image]

In this screen sort call have set "Configure Template". I have set "b2bPg_payPage_upiCollect_failure". After I have tried to enter the wrong pin still success message get. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the merchantId for which you are setting the template?
Also, to test the above template, you need to need fetch collect from the simulator app & then do the payment from the app, which will ideally fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).